# Plotting a histogram with python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i just want to plot an very easy histogram in python, but it doesnt workt.

I am importing the data from excel via and converting it into a pd dataframe

```
data = pd.read_excel ("test.xlsx",sheet_name='new_tests', na_filter=True)
data_1= pd.DataFrame(data , columns=['x','y'])
```

x is a list of the form 1,2,3,....,100 and y are corresponding events of my modle for example 107, 208,.... and also of course 100 entries.

Now I want to plot a simple histogram with for example 10 bins - that means in the first bin are the summed events from [1,2,....,10]=[107,208,...] but

plt.hist(x,y,bins=20) doesnt work, since the plot is empty.

Comment: Please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: `plt.hist(x,y,bins=20)` what are `x` and `y` here? You haven't defined them. Did you mean `data_1["x"]`?

Comment: @Dan Sorry! sure yes data_1['x']

Comment: Have you tried df.plot.hist? -https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html

Comment: x and y values are always twisted

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation of plt.hist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)

> matplotlib.pyplot.hist(x, bins=None, range=None, density=False,
> weights=None, cumulative=False, bottom=None, histtype='bar',
> align='mid', orientation='vertical', rwidth=None, log=False,
> color=None, label=None, stacked=False, *, data=None, **kwargs)
>
> x(n,) array or sequence of (n,) arrays Input values, this takes either
> a single array or a sequence of arrays which are not required to be of
> the same length.
>
> binsint or sequence or str, default: rcParams["hist.bins"] (default:
> 10) If bins is an integer, it defines the number of equal-width bins
> in the range.
>
> If bins is a sequence, it defines the bin edges, including the left
> edge of the first bin and the right edge of the last bin; in this
> case, bins may be unequally spaced. All but the last (righthand-most)
> bin is half-open.

Aka following the documentation, you are setting the bin edges using y. You should be just inputting the recorded data values as x inthe plt.hist function and setting the number of bins. Try:

```
plt.hist(y, bins=20)
```

Comment: no it doesnt work because its counting how many times for example the value "5" is in the list of y-values